# Transformation of $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^n}$ in Euclidean space: Tensor or not?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, general-relativity

Let $A_i$ transforms as a covariant vector. Then, how does the quantity $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^n}$ transform under coordinate transformations? $$\frac{\partial A^\prime_k}{\partial x^{\prime m}}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime k}}\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{\prime m}}\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^n}+\frac{\partial^2 x^i}{\partial x^{\prime m}\partial x^{\prime k}}A_i$$

Consider two different coordinate transformations: (i) Rotation of a Cartesian coordinate into another and (ii) change from Cartesian to Spherical polar coordinates. In the first case, the second term is **zero** because the transformation coefficients are constants. *So it behaves like a tensor*. In the second case, the second term is **nonzero**. *So it doesn't behave like a tensor*.

So what should one say? Is the object $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^n}$ a tensor in Euclidean space or not?

**Note** I'm a student of physics and my knowledge of mathematical terminologies are limited. So please answer in simple language. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second term should **always** be zero for the object to be a tensor, so the object $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^n}\equiv \partial_n A_i$ is **not** a tensor. This is exactly the motivation behind introducing the **covariant derivative**, which is the appropriate modification of the normal derivative so that the object $\nabla_n A_i$ never has the second term and is therefore a tensor.